# How can i fetch record fast using php mysql?

Tags: php, pdo

I have more than 148494 emails in the database. I need to fetch and show in the checkbox value attribute using foreach or while loop. The problem is that it taking so much time. I want to reduce the time. I tried different method and normalize the query as i can but still facing same issue.

**What i tried**

**Method One:**

I made functions and store all the record into the array and then again i add for-each loop for showing the record (with html) from that array. I think it is bad one because it is taking too much time than other.

```
final function getActiveEmailArr(){
        $getEmailArr = array();
        $start      = (isset($_GET['start']))? (int)$_GET['start']:0;
        $end        = (isset($_GET['end']))? (int)$_GET['end']:100;
        $u_id       = (isset($_SESSION['USERID']))? (int)$_SESSION['USERID']:0;

        $EmailSts=$this->pdoConnection->prepare("select * from `ws_email` where `u_id` = :u_id and `we_status` = :we_status ORDER BY we_email ASC limit 0, 74247 ");

        $EmailSts->bindParam(':u_id', $u_id);
        $EmailSts->bindParam(':we_status', $we_status);
        $we_status = 1;
        $u_id = $u_id;
        $EmailSts->execute();
        while ($row = $EmailSts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $getEmailArr[] = $row;
        }
        return $getEmailArr;
    }
```

**Method Two:**

In this method i tried to store the email values with html into $html variable and then simply call the function, but it is also taking so much time for showing records.

```
final function getActiveEmailArr(){
        $html = '';
        $getEmailArr = array();
        $u_id       = (isset($_SESSION['USERID']))? (int)$_SESSION['USERID']:0;
        $EmailSts=$this->pdoConnection->prepare("select * from `ws_email` where `u_id` = :u_id and `we_status` = :we_status ORDER BY we_email ASC limit 100, 148300 ");

        $EmailSts->bindParam(':u_id', $u_id);
        $EmailSts->bindParam(':we_status', $we_status);
        $we_status = 1;
        $u_id = $u_id;
        $EmailSts->execute();
        $cc = 0;
        while ($row = $EmailSts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if ($cc % 50 == 0){ $html .='<b>'.$cc.'</b>';}
            $html .='<div class="input-group">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                  <label>
                                    <input id="login-remember" class="checkbox_j" type="checkbox" name="sendEmails[]" value="'.$row['we_email'].'">
                                    '.$row['we_email'].'</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>';
        $cc++;}
        return $html;
    }
```

I also tried to play with `Limit` it is good one but when i am trying this logic in the query `Limit 100, 148300` then it is also taking lot of time. Because query is counting 148300 record then selecting 100 after 148300 so i think that's why it is taking time in this condition, this is what i am thinking but i am not sure because i am not expert and still learning so please excuse if i made mistake in this question.

Comment: `limit 100, 148300` is starting at 100 all the way to the end. Perhaps `limit 100,100` to show 100 records at a time or similar

Comment: @RamRaider I am not sure i am right or not but as per my understanding  `limit 100, 148300` query will count the record till `148300` and then select   `100` am i right?

Comment: no. it will start at row 100 and select all rows until 148300 or rather select 148300 records after row 100

Comment: @RamRaider Okay Thanks. So i think my sentence is fit on this `limit  148300, 100` now my above sentence is correct for this ?

Comment: yep - that would start at row 148300 and select 100 records from that point

Comment: What indexes you have on your table? Also try implementing some pagination, like loading 100 records per page and than do ajax calls to load more

Comment: @Justinas what do you means by indexes? Are you asking about primary id?? if so then primary id is `we_id`

Comment: @Mr.Developer If you are working with `u_id` and `we_status` then put indexes on them

Comment: @Justinas I am sorry can you please explain it. Thank You